# Convert string with time zone offset to datetime in Athena

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

There is a column of type varchar in MySQL table that contains datetime data like
‘2021-08-17 06:55:22.819-0400’ which has the time zone offset information included.

How can it be converted to datetime(3) in a select statement in Athena?
Basically ‘2021-08-17 06:55:22.819-0400’  >>> 2021-08-17 10:55:22.819

Comment: Are you querying a MySQL database from Amazon Athena?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`parse_datetime`](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/datetime.html#parse_datetime) function, like this:

```sql
SELECT parse_datetime('2021-08-17 06:55:22.819-0400', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ')
```

If you want the time converted to UTC you can append `AT TIME ZONE 'Z'`, like this:

```sql
SELECT parse_datetime('2021-08-17 06:55:22.819-0400', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ') AT TIME ZONE 'Z'
```

Comment: Thank you. Works but needs removing 'UTC' at the end of output.

Comment: You can use [`format_datetime`](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/datetime.html#format_datetime), something like this: `format_datetime(parse_datetime(…), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'))`

Answer (score 1):

If all dates are exactly in this format you can replace space with `T` and use [`from_iso8601_timestamp`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#from_iso8601_timestamp), which will return `timestamp with time zone` and then you can handle timezone either using `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` or just custing to `timezone`:

```sql
select cast(from_iso8601_timestamp(replace('2021-08-17 06:55:22.819-0400', ' ', 'T')) AS timestamp)
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2021-08-17 10:55:22.819 |